# How is the Longest Common Sub-sequence of two sequences is a special case of the Sequence Alignment problem?

Tags: algorithms, subsequences

Could anyone briefly show me how the Longest Common Sub-sequence of two sequences is a special case of the Sequence Alignment problem? I cannot wrap my head around this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you state the two problems formally? There might be different versions out there, so this will help us understand your question better.

Comment: I think the answer below, explained it well and connected the dots for me. But thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of finding a longest common subsequence can be answered by
computing the alignment where match is rewarded by +1 while mismatch and
insdel penalty are both 0.

Comment: Ooh, okay thank you! That makes so much sense now.